# How to used ROS_CANopen?

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am quite new to ROS . I want to use ros_canopen package to communicate with the robot  in my lab, i.e. build a ros controller for it. However , I cant find a more detail tutorial to use it than the general intro on wiki.org .

HardWare and resources：

1. A [USB-to-CAN compact](http://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/pc-interfaces/pc-can-interfaces/details-pc-can-interfaces)  is used to communicate between my laptop and the robot . This USB-to-CAN provids a Linux driver called [ECI](http://www.ixxat.com/support/file-and-documents-download/drivers/eci-driver) and an EDS file for configuring CANopen devices.
2. The robot uses Maxon motors and [Copley driver boards(Accelnet Micro Module)](http://www.copleycontrols.com/Motion/Downloads/index.html). Copley provides a Copley Motion Lib([CML](http://www.copleycontrols.com/Motion/Downloads/index.html)).

ros_canopen seems only support socketcan![](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen?

How can I set up my laptop to communicate with CAN bus.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 with Indigo installed.

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233735/how-to-used-ros_canopen?/) by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-05-06**:
As JuliusGel pointed out, try to install the ixxat socketcan driver: http://www.ixxat.com/support/file-and-documents-download/drivers/socketcan-driver (see the README!).
The ros wiki pages on socketcan_interface and canopen_motor_node give some additional hints.
Feel free to add what's missing.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-06**:
Thank you for the repaid replies. The  ixxat socketcan driver works. Thx again !

So i'm trying to configure canopen_motor_node. Here I found a repo using ros_canopen [https://github.com/jlarraez/schunk_lwa4p/blob/master/launch/robot.launch] . I'm trying to write a launch file to start canopen_motor

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-06**:
with a can.yaml and a node.yaml. However it threw out a canopen::ParseException. Are there other projects that use ros_canopen? Maybe I could borrow some of their codes to launch canopen_motor.

Thank you very much.

**Comment by [Will](https://answers.ros.org/users/26900/will/) on 2016-05-18**:
Hi. I'm in the same situation with you. I use the same hardware and have no idea what to do next. Can we communicate by e-mail? I think that is more efficient and will save lots of time. My e-mail address is xiangpeng@buaa.edu.cn. Look forward to your letter.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-05-18**:
Hi @Will... just wanted to let you know that I moved your answer to be a comment. Answers are specifically reserved for answers. Best of luck getting your situation resolved!

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-05-19**:
The Care-O-bot 4 uses ros_canopen for 27 motors (`cob_hardware_config`).
Some examples can be found in https://github.com/ipa320/canopen_test_utils
And `schunk_robots` works as well.

The `ParseException` is triggered from errors in the EDS (or bugs in the parser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you are using [**this**](http://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/pc-interfaces/pc-can-interfaces/details-pc-can-interfaces) USB-to-CAN device.
You are right ros_canopen only supports SocketCAN interface. If you want to use another kernel driver i.e. ECI you will have to implement a custom driver plugin. You could have a look at how socketcan_interface is implemented in ros_canopen [**here**](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/tree/indigo-devel/socketcan_interface).

That being said it seems that your USB-to-CAN device also supports SocketCAN. The driver is located [**here**](http://www.ixxat.com/support/file-and-documents-download/drivers/socketcan-driver). So you could have a look at it.

Another question is does your robot use OpenCAN protocol? If it does not then ros_canopen package might not be suitable for you at all. And even if your robot does support OpenCAN you might have to implement additional profiles because ros_canopen for now only supports basic (301) and motion control (402) profiles. But I can not comment on that more without knowing what robot you are trying to control.

Hopefully that helps to clarify things a bit.

---

Originally posted by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) with karma: 433 on 2016-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-05-06**:
This answer sums it up pretty well!
The CAN layer can be customized with a `can::DriverInterface` plugin.
If your motor does not support the 402 profile you can provide a `canopen::MotorBase::Allocator` plugin and reuse the `ros_control` interfaces of `canopen_motor_node`.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-09**:
Thx. The socketcan driver you gave did work! Now I'm trying to run the canopen_motor_node.There seems to be some problems in the code. Which branch of ros_canopen would you recommond? Indigo-devel or indigo-release-candidate?

**Comment by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) on 2016-05-09**:
I believe indigo-devel should be the most up to date code.